# Spotfire to DAX Power BI conversion

Tags: powerbi, dax, spotfire, spotfire-analyst

**Trying to covert Spotfire calculated column in DAX**
case
when ([SIHP]=0) or ([SIHP] is null) then null
when (Max([SIHP]) over (Intersect([Job ID],Previous([SIIN],1))) is null) and (Abs([SIHP] - [NSHP])>50) then "Fail"
when Abs([SIHP] - [PSHP)>50 then "Fail"
else "Pass"
end
**
Please help me in converting to DAX .
Thanks in advance **

I tried using maxx function for over in spotfire. But stuck at intersect and previous and abs functions.